# How to insert variable into sscanf string?

Tags: c, scanf

I am extracting data from file with:

```
sscanf (match, "cpu %d %d %d...", &user1, &nice1, &kernel1, &idl...);
```

My problem starts when I try to read it for N cores in a loop:

```
sscanf (match, "cpu0 %d %d..", &user1, &nic...);
sscanf (match, "cpu1 %d %d..", &user1, &nic...);
sscanf (match, "cpu2 %d %d...", &user1, &nic...);
```

Is there any way to insert decimal variable to this sscanf in C?

Edit:
I want to increment number next to "cpu" string to get "cpu**0** %d %d", "cpu**1** %d %d", "cpu**2** %d %d"

Edit2 + solution:

```
/* Locate the line that starts with "cpuX " */
match = strstr (buffer, cpux);
/* Parse the line and extract data */
sscanf (match, "%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", *&cpuXgarbage,&...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but it is probably the wrong way to do it.

Instead of putting cpu0 in your sscanf string, why not a %s? Read the cpu0 into a string. Then it does not matter if it matches or not. You could have a read loop that looks for "cpu" at the start and stops when it doesn't match.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try it. brb

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    sprintf(format, "cpu%d blah blah", i);
    sscanf(match, format, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int user[20];
int nic[20];
int i = 0;
sscanf (match, "cpu0 %d %d..", &(user[i++]), &(nic[i++])...);
sscanf (match, "cpu0 %d %d..", &(user[i++]), &(nic[i++])...);
.....
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I want to increment number next to "cpu" so I'll get cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4 in this loop.